# Убрать из списка или добавить картинку участника

Tags: дефект, предложение, модерация, выборы

В разделе [Выборы модераторов сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election), в результатах выборов за 2015-ый год, есть сломанная картинка/сслыка на победившего участника

Если смысл в том чтобы показывать историю полностью, независимо от того сейчас есть участник или нет, то предлагаю хотя бы как обычную картинку показать как тут [было например](https://web.archive.org/web/20160805150301/http://ru.stackoverflow.com/election)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если смысл в том чтобы НЕ показывать не существующего участника, тогда предлагаю просто удалить его из списка

##### UPD

Как показал [@αλεχολυτ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%b5%cf%87%ce%bf%ce%bb%cf%85%cf%84) должна быть не картинка, которую я откопал, а картинка с надписью, о том что пользователя больше нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю переводить как "АККАУНТ УДАЛЁН" т.к. больше оригинального текста всего на 2 символа, что может быть важно, если будет принципально уместить всё в одну строку, тогда размер шрифта не придётся сильно уменьшать относительно оригинала

Comment: Что-то пошло не так. Должно быть примерно как на десятых [выборах enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/election)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну можно и так :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А у этой картинки есть уже аналог на русском языке или предложить несколько вариантов перевода текста?

Comment: Сделал [картинку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDcQm.png). P.S. не судите строго сделал на коленках)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Убран?)) Как будто ненужная вещь была и вот его убрали) Я явно буду против такого перевода. Я бы предложил что-то типа "учётная запись удалена" или "аккаунт удалён" или "пользователь удалён". "Убран" как по мне тут явно не подходит

Comment: @EzioMercer это легко исправляется, момент.

Comment: @EzioMercer [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbHaQ.png) лучше?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ну это мой же вариант, конечно, я скажу что лучше)) Но вообще я бы не писал каждое слово с большой буквы, либо как предложение, где только первое слово с большой, либо как в английской версии всё с большой. Но учитывая что в русском слова обычно длиннее, то чтобы уместить всё в одну строку надо будет сильно уменьшить размер ширфта, потому надо подбирать максимально короткий текст, потому как по мне "аккаунт удалён" лучше всех подходит, если надо будет писать всё большими. А ещё не забываем про сами шрифты, не думаю что менять их - хорошая идея

Comment: @EzioMercer не совсем уверен что "аккаунт", подойдёт, как по мне лучше подходит "участник" - [картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhue1.png)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Не буду с этим спорить, я просто искал максимально короткие, но подходящие слова, потому остановился на слове "аккаунт". Предлагаю опубликовать варианты перевода в картинке как ответ, чтобы не приходилось постоянно открывать ссылки из комментариев, а сразу всё было бы перед глазами ну и дополнять можно при желании. Всё рано одна из тем - обсуждение, так что такой ответ не будет лишним

Comment: Я запостил вопрос на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388464/339911). Согласно статусу на него уже обратили внимание сотрудники.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Отлчино, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Различные варианты картинки ["USER REMOVED"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuXwq.png) на русском:

| # | текст | изображение |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Пользователь убран | [image] |
| 2 | Пользователь удалён | [image] |
| 3 | Участник удалён | [image] |
| 4 | Аккаунт удалён | [image] |